# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'sshagent' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkins CI/CD and do the building for the script below

```
def secret = 'server'
def server = 'jenkins@103.171.85.155'
def directory = 'wayshub-frontend'
def branch = 'master'

pipeline{
        agent any
    stages{
            stage ('compose down and pull'){
            steps{
                sshagent([secret]) {
                    sh '''
                    ssh -o StrictHostkeyChecking=no ${server} << EOF
                    cd ${directory}
                    docker-compose down
                    docker system prune -f
                    git pull origin ${branch}
                    exit
                    EOF
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    stage ('build images'){
            steps{
                sshagent([secret]) {
                    sh '''
                    ssh -o StrictHostkeyChecking=no ${server} << EOF
                    cd ${directory}
                    docker-compose build
                    exit
                    EOF
                    '''
                 }
             }
        }
        stage ('deploy'){
            steps{
                sshagent([secret]) {
                    sh '''
                    ssh -o StrictHostkeyChecking=no ${server} << EOF
                    cd ${directory}
                    docker-compose up -d
                    exit
                    EOF
            '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i got error during build

[Error build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKMPf.png)

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'sshagent' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, findBuildScans, getContext, git, input, isUnix, junit, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, node, parallel, powershell, properties, publishChecks, publishHTML, pwd, pwsh, readFile, readTrusted, resolveScm, retry, script, sh, sleep, stage, stash, step, timeout, timestamps, tm, tool, unarchive, unstable, unstash, validateDeclarativePipeline, waitUntil, warnError, withChecks, withContext, withCredentials, withDockerContainer, withDockerRegistry, withDockerServer, withEnv, withGradle, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [GitUsernamePassword, all, allBranchesSame, allOf, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome, antTarget, any, anyOf, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, authorizationMatrix, batchFile, bitbucketServer, booleanParam, branch, brokenBuildSuspects, brokenTestsSuspects, buildButton, buildDiscarder, buildDiscarders, buildRetention, buildUser, buildingTag, builtInNode, caseInsensitive, caseSensitive, certificate, changeRequest, changelog, changeset, checkoutToSubdirectory, choice, choiceParam, cleanWs, clock, command, contributor, credentials, cron, crumb, culprits, defaultFolderConfiguration, defaultView, demand, developers, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, docker, dockerCert, dockerServer, dockerTool, dockerfile, downstream, dumb, durabilityHint, email-ext, envVars, envVarsFilter, environment, equals, expression, extendedEmailPublisher, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, fingerprints, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, fromDocker, fromScm, fromSource, git, gitBranchDiscovery, gitHubBranchDiscovery, gitHubBranchHeadAuthority, gitHubExcludeArchivedRepositories, gitHubExcludeForkedRepositories, gitHubExcludePrivateRepositories, gitHubExcludePublicRepositories, gitHubForkDiscovery, gitHubIgnoreDraftPullRequestFilter, gitHubPullRequestDiscovery, gitHubSshCheckout, gitHubTagDiscovery, gitHubTopicsFilter, gitHubTrustContributors, gitHubTrustEveryone, gitHubTrustNobody, gitHubTrustPermissions, gitTagDiscovery, gitUsernamePassword, github, githubProjectProperty, githubPush, gradle, headRegexFilter, headWildcardFilter, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, inheriting, inheritingGlobal, installSource, isRestartedRun, jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jgitapache, jnlp, jobBuildDiscarder, jobName, junitTestResultStorage, label, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, legacySCM, list, local, location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, mailer, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenGlobalConfig, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, modernSCM, myView, namedBranchesDifferent, newContainerPerStage, node, nodeProperties, nonInheriting, none, not, organizationFolder, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parallelsAlwaysFailFast, parameters, password, pattern, permanent, pipeline, pipeline-model, pipeline-model-docker, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, pollSCM, preserveStashes, projectNamingStrategy, proxy, pruneTags, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, rateLimit, rateLimitBuilds, recipients, requestor, resourceRoot, retainOnlyVariables, run, runParam, sSHLauncher, schedule, scmRetryCount, scriptApproval, scriptApprovalLink, search, security, shell, simpleBuildDiscarder, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, slave, sourceRegexFilter, sourceWildcardFilter, ssh, sshPublicKey, sshUserPrivateKey, standard, status, string, stringParam, suppressAutomaticTriggering, suppressFolderAutomaticTriggering, swapSpace, tag, teamSlugFilter, text, textParam, timestamper, timestamperConfig, timezone, tmpSpace, toolLocation, triggeredBy, unsecured, untrusted, upstream, upstreamDevelopers, userSeed, usernameColonPassword, usernamePassword, viewsTabBar, weather, withAnt, x509ClientCert, zip] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, params, pipeline, scm]
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:219)

Github repository : https://github.com/pinoezz/Jenkins-Frontend

Guess what's wrong please help

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not installed the sshagent plugin. [Here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/) is the documentation for the plugin. Go to manage Jenkins and make sure it's installed.